# Remove index values partially from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I have a dataframe as below.

[image]

How do I convert this into a dataframe as below

[image]

PS : It must be noted that the dataframe in the first image is the output of a pivot_table()

Comment: What is your `pivot_table()` code?

Comment: Please don't post the data in images. This would make difficult for debugging.

Comment: Apologies for having said the details on an image. The pivot table code is                
                                                                                                                      
table = pd.pivot_table(df_mysql , index=['Activityid','Manager' , 'Employee','Village'],columns=['ActivityName','AttributeName'],values=['Reading'], aggfunc='first')

table = table.reset_index(level = ['Activityid','Manager' , 'Employee','Village'],col_level=2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need:

```
df_mysql = pd.DataFrame({
        'Village':list('abcdef'),
        'Employee':list('abcdef'),
         'Manager':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
         'Activityid':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
         'AttributeName':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
         'ActivityName':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
         'Reading':list('aaabbb')
})
```

First remove `[]` around `'Reading'`:

```
table = pd.pivot_table(df_mysql , 
                       index=['Activityid','Manager' , 'Employee','Village'],
                       columns=['ActivityName','AttributeName'],
                       values='Reading', 
                       aggfunc='first')
print (table)
ActivityName                           2    3    4    5    6    9
AttributeName                          1    3    0    1    5    7
Activityid Manager Employee Village                              
2          5       e        e          b  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
3          4       f        f        NaN  NaN    b  NaN  NaN  NaN
4          5       d        d        NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN    b
7          4       a        a        NaN  NaN  NaN    a  NaN  NaN
8          5       b        b        NaN    a  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
9          4       c        c        NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN    a  NaN
```

then remove first level of `MultiIndex`, remove columns names and convert `MultiIndex` to columns:

```
df = table.reset_index(level=0, drop=True).rename_axis((None, None), axis=1).reset_index()
```

Then reorder empty values of levels with list comprehension:

```
L = [(a, b) if b != '' else (b, a) for a, b in df.columns]
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(L)
print (df)
                              2    3    4    5    6    9
  Manager Employee Village    1    3    0    1    5    7
0       5        e       e    b  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1       4        f       f  NaN  NaN    b  NaN  NaN  NaN
2       5        d       d  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN    b
3       4        a       a  NaN  NaN  NaN    a  NaN  NaN
4       5        b       b  NaN    a  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
5       4        c       c  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN    a  NaN
```

And last if necessary convert to file:

```
df.to_excel('file.xlsx', index=False)
```

Comment: Thanks jezrael. This gives me the manager, employee,village on a different level with attributes. I want all of them on the same line. Also, the first column in my original post is not going away

Comment: @RathiRao - Anwer was completley changed, please test it.

Comment: jezrael - The repeated values must appear for the manager column. This is the requirement I have. The code you have sent removes the duplication and merges the cell. I want repeated data with unmerged cells

Comment: jezrael - Thanks. I am unable to understand why the list comprehension was used. Will you please explain?

Comment: @RathiRao - Because if use `reset_index()` values are in first row. And need in second row.

Comment: The solution worked !! Thank you very much ... But I get the error NotImplementedError: Writing to Excel with MultiIndex columns and no index ('index'=False) is not yet implemented. How do I take out that index?